# How do I determine if an index is a list/array or not?

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing

I am essentially trying to work out if a specified index is a list or not. I have a list embedded into an index.

This is what I have so far

```py
    if len(hashTable[hashed-1])>1:
        hashTable[hashed-1].append(inVal)
    else:
        tempTable = [hashTable[hashed-1], inVal]  
        hashTable[hashed-1] = tempTable
        print(inVal,hashed)
        print(hashTable)
```

The output of the list is: (the 0's an 10 are irrelevant)

```py
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, [1, 3], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10]
```

The error is:

```py
    if len(hashTable[hashed-1])>1:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: `hashTable[hashed-1]` is an int, not a list, hence the error, try `if isinstance(hashTable[hashed-1], list) and len(hashTable[hashed-1]) > 1`

Comment: Look at my comment or the answer given by @Massifox

Comment: Thank you, the if isinstance(hashTable[hashed-1], list) worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance), to check if your object is a list type, as follows:

```
isinstance(hashTable[hashed-1], list)
```

in your case:

```
if isinstance(hashTable[hashed-1], list) and len(hashTable[hashed-1]) > 1
```

Python uses lazy evaluation, to evaluate the condition in this if-statement. So `len(hashTable[hashed-1])` will be called only when `isinstance(hashTable[hashed-1], list)` is `True`.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't realise it was that simple :)